# CakePHP asking for model table despite useTable = false

Tags: cakephp

I'm creating a contact form to send an email to a specified address. I'm trying to utilize CakePHP model validations and since I don't need a table for the contact model, I've set useTable to false in the contact model. 
Yet I'm getting an error in the controller function that does the sending. The error is

> Missing Database Table
>   Error: Database table contacts for model Contact was not found.

pointing to the line that makes the first call to $this->Contact:

> $this->Contact->validates( $this->data );

I thought this was all good to go with the CakePHP framework. Why am I wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit**: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11617213/41874) (and [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481936/cakephp-asking-for-model-table-despite-usetable-false/1486855#comment34488970_11617213)) for CakePHP 2.x (model file should be called `Contact.php`)

---

**CakePHP 1.x** - Verify that your model file is called `contact.php` (lowercase). If it is not, CakePHP won't find your model and and will instead create an "autoModel" on runtime called `Contact` which uses the `contacts` table.

Comment: wowsers. i went over that a few times myself, not until now realizing i named it  contact.ctp  out of view creating habit. i feel like a goober.

Comment: hehe, we've all been there. one that got me pretty good once was `actsAs` vs `actAs`, hours wasted.

Answer (score 4):

This is a top result to a search but the information is outdated I think.

In CakePHP 2.0+ you need to set `$useTable = false;` in the model, the model name uses propercase (so it should be `Contact` and not `contact` as suggested) and the controller must have `$uses = 'Contact';` or `$uses = array('Contact');` or cake generates default model properties and tries to load a table that doesn't exist. So both of these things must be set for it to work.

Comment: Like in the @deizel answer, verify that your model file is called Contact.php (uppercase in CakePHP 2.x). If it is not, CakePHP won't find your model and your any unique table definitions using $useTable.

Answer (score 3):

Two things made the difference for me -- changing the file name of my model to Contact.php (instead of ContactModel.php) and commenting out `var $uses = 'Contact';` in my ContactController.php.

Also, many of the tutorials out there for contact forms are for earlier versions of CakePHP. Be sure to use the correct form input structure. Here is the view for mine in Cake 2.1:

```
<?php 
    echo $this->Form->create('Contact');
    echo $this->Form->inputs();
    echo $this->Form->end('Send');

?>
```

Comment: here is a 2.x one, as well: http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/12/15/tools-plugin-part-2-contact-form/ - using a schema

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip on renaming SomethingModel.php to Something.php. I had exactly the same problem and was about to go mad looking for the source of my problem :-)

Comment: I had this same problem, but I just accidentally fixed it before reading this solution.

Answer (score 2):

If memory serves, you're not actually setting your model:

```
$this->Contact->set( $this->data );
$this->Contact->validates();
```

In your code, the model isn't actually populated when you try to validate it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a model without a table you also need to set a schema eg

```
class Contact extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Contact';
    var $useTable = false;
    var $_schema = array(
        'name' => array('type' => 'string', 'length' => 255),
        'email' => array('type' => 'string', 'length' => 255),
        'message' => array('type' => 'text')
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it helps anyone, I found that if I had

```
var $uses = 'ModelName';
```

in my controller, it will override useTable. Remove it if you don't need it.