# Validation rules are not being applied on create in cakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

The problem I am having is that the validation rules are being fired on edit, but none of them are fired on create. Here are few of the validation rules, even though the problem is most probably not here:

```
var $validate = array(

        'date' => array(
            'notempty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'Choose a date'
            )
            ),

        'minutes' => array(
            'rule'=>'minutes',
            'message' => 'Minutes cannot exceed 60',
            'allowEmpty' => true
        )
```

And here are the forms (edit and add):

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Event');?>

    <?php echo $this->Form->input('date', array('class'=>'datepicker', 'type'=>'text', 'label'=>__('Date*')));?>

<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Save edit'));?>



<?php echo $this->Form->create('Event');?>      

    <?php   echo $this->Form->input('date', array('class'=>'datepicker', 'type'=>'text', 'value'=>$date, 'label'=>__('Date*'))); ?>

<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Save'));?>
```

And the validation is not disabled in any controller function as they are the same all over the app and work perfectly with every other model. I guess it has to be something simple, but I just cannot get it to work.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by this title?

Comment: That the validation rules are not being applied on create. I will update the title, thanks for remark.

Comment: validation on default will be apply on update and create

Comment: I know that, and that is actually the case with all of the other model, except from this one.

Comment: `debug(get_class($this->Event)); die;` in your Controller. If it's "AppModel" your model file is misnamed. If it's "Event" you need to show more info - such as your controller action, and what you're actually submitting.

Comment: did you load App::uses('AppModel', 'Model'); on top of your EventModel

Comment: possible duplicate of [CakePHP asking for model table despite useTable = false](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481936/cakephp-asking-for-model-table-despite-usetable-false)

Comment: update your question with whole `model`, `controller` and the `view`.. and also with `debug($this->request->data)` on `create`;

Comment: Are you doing update and add on events controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code in your EventsController.php file.

**In your add() function:**

Code:

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {

  $this->Event->set($this->request->data);

  if($this->Event->validates()) {

      if ($this->Event->save($this->request->data)) {

         // Data saved and validated

      }

  }

}
```

I hope this code will help you..

Thank You!!

Answer (score 1):

you just need to use validation rules in both actions on model table separately.

```
public function validationadd(Validator $validator){
    ->notEmpty('first_name');
    return $validator;
}
public function validationedit(Validator $validator){
    ->notEmpty('first_name');
    return $validator;
}
```